# Identifying the gap in the solution of ratio/proportion problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem statement,

`A jar full of whiskey contains 40% alcohol. A part of this whisky is replaced by another containing 19% alcohol, and now the percentage of alcohol was found to be 26%. The quantity of whisky replaced is`

options

```
a) 1/3 b) 2/3 c) 2/5 d) 3/5
```

Let's say originally we have l1 amount of whiskey, which gives 0.4 * l1 alcohol;

Let's say we take out l2 amount of whiskey which means,

that we remove 0.4 * l2 amount of alcohol,

and we replace it with 0.19 * l2 amount of alcohol.

So, we have the equation,

( 0.4 * l1 - 0.4 * l2 + 0.19 * l2 ) / (l1) = 0.26

l1 = 150 l2.

Originally we had 150 * l2 *0.4 = 60 * l2;

Currently we have 150 * l2 * 0.26 = 39 * l2

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you write $l_1=150l_2$ and not $l_1=1.5l_2$? Other than that, what gives you the idea that you have done something wrong?

Comment: @DavidK because I don't have the answer.

Comment: @DavidK Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generally speaking, when solving a word problem, you may want to assign some symbols (such as $l_1$, in your attempt here) to quantities in the problem, and you want to do this in a way such that you can express the answer in terms of these symbols. You might try to figure out what $l_1$ and $l_2$ have to do with the answer to the problem. If you can do that **before** you start doing algebra with the given numbers, there is less chance that you'll waste time figuring out things that don't matter.

Comment: @DavidK Can you help me with the solution? What am I doing wrong? I have already explained what I have done, in great detail? Is the question even correct?